# Javascript closures bug

Tags: javascript, closures, javascript-objects

I have been severely bitten by Javascript's closures bug a few days ago, but was too busy to ask. I am trying something like the following with the `jQuery` template engine.

```
<ul id="container"></ul>
<script type="text/jq-tmpl" id="myTmpl">
  <li>
    <span style="background:#fafafa">X:${X}</span>
    <span style="background:#ababab">Y:${Inner.Y}</span>
    <span style="background:#9a9a9a">Z:${Inner.Z}</span>
  </li>
</script>

function OuterObject(x,y,z){
  this.X = x;
  this.Inner = InnerObject(y,z);
}

function InnerObject(y,z){
  this.Y=y;
  this.Z=z;
}

$(function(){
  var l=[];
  l.push(OuterObject(1,"One","inner-1"));
  l.push(OuterObject(2,"Two","inner-2"));
  $("#myTmpl").tmpl(l).appendTo("#container");
});
```

The problem is that it shows `inner-2` and `Two` for both the items rendered. I have also tried it like this:

```
var a=OuterObject(1,"One","inner-1");
l.push(a);
var b=OuterObject(2,"Two","inner-2");
l.push(b);
```

But is all the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need to use 'new' when calling your constructor functions.

e.g. `new Outerobject(...)` and `new InnerObject(...)`

Otherwise, the `this` object won't be returned.

Comment: And `this` inside the functions will be `window`.

Comment: @muistooshort don't tell me. It is from here http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp (2. Create an object constructor). Then what is recommended to use in functions instead of `this`?

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot: (1) [Don't trust w3fools](http://w3fools.com/) (2) `this` will be `window` unless you use `new`.

Comment: @muistooshort so if I use `var x=new InnerObject()` the `this` refers to current scope, else it refers to `window`. thanks dear. this is really an eye opener.